# Finding derivative when an identity is given

Tags: derivatives

Question-:If $(1+x^2)^{1/2}+(1+y^2)^{1/2}=x+y$

Then find dy/dx.

My attempt-:

[image]

I want to know whether am i correct or not.

The options are-:

[image]

Comment: You do not need to make any substituions with trig functions. Do you know implicit differentiation?

Comment: The substitution approach is not correct unless you take in consideration $du$.

Comment: You are assuming that $x^2+y^2=1$. But this is not given.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the question.

Since $(1+x^2)^{\frac12}+(1+y^2)^{\frac12}>|x|+|y|\ge |x+y|\ge y$, there is no $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the chain rule we get
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}+\frac{yy'}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}=1+y'$$
Can you finish?
Solving this equation for $y'$ we get
$$y'=\frac{\sqrt{1+y^2}(1-\sqrt{1+x^2})}{(\sqrt{1+y^2}-y)\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Comment: I tried this one but answer is not matching can you please solve i have the options i will edit it

Comment: So what can we say abput the answer how will i solve further its still not matching with any options